# Why is this convergence test incorrect?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

We can assure that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} $ , $\frac{n}{1+n^2} \leq a_{n} \leq \frac{3n}{1+n^2} $. Therefore, does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converge, diverge or we cannot assure anything?

I had thought that because of the Squeeze Theorem:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{1+n^2} \leq a_{n} \leq \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3n}{1+n^2}$$

$$0 \leq a_{n} \leq 0$$

Therefore as $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n} = 0$ we cannot assure anything.

Although, seeing the actual solution to this question, it says that we can assure it is divergent. I'm just unsure how I could prove that.

Comment: (1)  What is $a_n$?  (2)  Your first inequality is false if $n$ is negative.

Comment: Are you certain that $n\in \Bbb R$? Does $\displaystyle a_\pi$ make sense? (Also loads of people here in the comment section answering the question. I don't think that's how it's supposed to be.)

Comment: Hint: we know that $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$$ diverges

Comment: Your series is above a divergent one, so use the comparison test.

Comment: note that the because $a_n\ge \frac{n}{1+n^2}$ and $H_n$ diverges, $\sum\limits_{n\ge0}a_n$ must also diverge.

Comment: if we can assume $ \frac{n}{1+n^2} \leq a_{n}\ \forall n\geq 0$ then we have $ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{1+n^2} \leq \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}$ and the series on the left diverges (why?)

Comment: Hint: $\frac{n}{1+n^2} \ge \frac{1}{2n}$, hence $a_n \ge  \frac{1}{2n}$. We know that $\sum_n \frac{1}{2n} = +\infty$ thus $\sum_n a_n$ diverges.

Comment: @Arthur I think you're right, I think that n belongs to the natural numbers, not the real numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the *sequence* $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $0$. But the *series* $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges, since you always have $a_n\geqslant\dfrac n{n^2+1}$ and the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac n{n^2+1}$ diverges (by the integral test, for instance).